# Get *exact* GPU name - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winapi, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

I need to get the exact name of an AMD graphics card using VB.
My code works for any Nvidia card:

```
Imports System.Management
      Dim query As New System.Management.SelectQuery("Win32_VideoController")
      Dim search As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
      Dim info As System.Management.ManagementObject
      For Each info In search.Get()
          msgBox(info("Caption").ToString)
          msgBox(info("VideoProcessor").ToString)
```

The above code returns:

"NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970" and "GeForce GTX 970".

That's fine for any Nvidia Card I throw at it, but it's not the same on AMD cards. I tried using an HD 6770 and got this:

"AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series" and "AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x68A)".

The second string isn't at all useful (Yes, I've looked up '0x68A', it means nothing) and the first string gives me the '6700' series. That could mean one of many cards. It's the same when I ran it on an R9 280X, it just said 'R9 200 Series'. I need to  be able to get the exact GPU name, it is crucial.

Thank you :)

Comment: If that's the information that AMD stores as the video processor for WMI to retrieve, that's what you're going to get back. Do you know for a fact that AMD stores something different in the registry for the controller `Caption` and `VideoProcessor`?

Comment: That, I am not sure of. If it is, then I guess I can't use WMI, in which case there is no other way of retrieving GPU information. I mean, I could always try `Name` or `Description`. They both yeild the same as `VideoProcessor` for my GTX 970, but perhaps it'll be different for AMD. I don't have access to an AMD card atm, so I'll have to try later.

Comment: If you don't have access to an AMD card, how do you *try using an HD 6770*? How do you know AMD doesn't return the information you're looking for?

Comment: I sent the program to a mate who tested it on his PC and sent me his results. He's not around at the moment, so I'll have to wait till tomorrow. And what do you mean by that last bit? (sorry, I'm tired).

Comment: I mean how do you know you have a problem if you have no access to an AMD card? If you have a *mate* that has an AMD video card, then you have access to one (just not at this moment).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I mean that I have a problem because my program isn't returning exact information about AMD cards, and it's  difficult to work around when I don't even own one, and I have to use a friend. Anyway, back to the code, can you think of anything?

Comment: I've already mentioned what I can think of - confirming that AMD stores something other than what you've obtained as a result. You don't have a problem until you have evidence of a problem. *Do you know for a fact that AMD stores something differently in the registry for the controller Caption and VideoProcessor than what you're retrieving?* You need to get a list of all of the values returned from a WMI query for `SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController` for your friend's AMD card.

Comment: Well my problem is that I don't know that. But thank you, I will do that as soon as I can. If the registry doesn't store it, is there any other option?

Comment: I can't offer a recommendation for a solution to a problem you don't know yet that you have. The solution might well be something other than WMI, but that's not clear yet.

Comment: Ok, I will get back to you once I have the values

Comment: You might also want to check if the CAPTION you get is actually different than that reported by DeviceManager.

Comment: Plutonix - Ok, I checked it and they are the same. 
KenWhite - I tried again with "Name" and "Description", and they both returned exactly the same as 'Caption', which was AMD Radeon R9 200 Series. So I gueses that means there is no way to get the exact GPU name using WMI (for AMD cards that is, Nvidia is fine). 

Are there any other methods of attaining the GPU name?